# Run SQL Code after ListView Web Server Control OnItemDeleted

Tags: sql, vb.net, listview

I have an ASP Classic background and getting to grips with VB.NET.

With a ListView generated through Visual Studio 2017 I also have delete buttons which delete entries within the ListView table.

I already have OnItemDeleted etc commands to DataBind other tables in my Web Form. But when an item is deleted, how do I retain the ID of the item which was deleted and run a separate piece of SQL code in the background to update another table.

Example of the tables:

[image: Illustrative Table]

So if a ListView displayed the contents of **Table: Items**, if an item is deleted within the ListView I would also like to run a piece of SQL code after the deletion to update/delete **Table: Cost**. So, if the entry for Shoes was deleted in the ListView then it would know the ItemID was 2 and then in the next table `DELETE FROM Cost WHERE ItemID = 2`.

Comment: Capture the ID in a handler for the itemselectionchanged event, or set up the key in the database to cascade the delete?

Comment: How would I Capture the ID in a handler for the itemselectionchanged event. Can you give an example. I'm pretty quick at adapting to new pieces of code. I just got stuck on this. Thanks for your help

Comment: I think the example in the MSDN should get you there: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Someone else may have a better solution for you to be honest. I don't have a ton of time at the moment and it was the first thing I thought of.